# Calculated Column or Measure for grouping prioritized tasks into sprints

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have task-related data ordered by Priority with corresponding Story Points that I would like to group into sprints.  I can calculate the Cumulative Points.  However, I'm struggling to create a measure (or even a calculated column) to forecast in which sprint the task will occur given a known Velocity.

Assume 'Velocity' = 10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbAHT.jpg)

My goal is to determine the forecast sprint as seen in the table image.  Basically, the sum of story points for a sprint cannot exceed the velocity.  Unfortunately, simply dividing the Cumulative Points by the Velocity and rounding doesn't work.  In this case, the 11th task would fall into sprint 3, but the total story points for the sprint would exceed the velocity.

I've reviewed Greg Deckler's [For/While solution](https://gregdeckler.com/2019/03/04/for-and-while-loops-in-dax/), but I couldn't get it to work for this problem. I'm fairly new to DAX, but I did try a variety of other options but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using Power Query / M language.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13},
        {2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 7, 2, 1, 1, 5, 3}
    }, type table [Priority = Int32.Type, Story Point = Int32.Type]),
    Velocity = 10,
    AddedSprint = Table.FromRecords(
        List.Accumulate(
            Table.ToRecords(Table.Sort(Source, "Priority")),
            [TotalSP = 0, CurrentSprint = 1, Value = {}],
            (state as record, record as record) as record =>
                let sp = record[Story Point],
                    nextState =
                        if state[TotalSP] + sp > Velocity then [
                            TotalSP = sp,
                            CurrentSprint = state[CurrentSprint] + 1,
                            Value = state[Value] & {record & [Sprint = CurrentSprint]}
                        ]
                        else [
                            TotalSP = state[TotalSP] + sp,
                            CurrentSprint = state[CurrentSprint],
                            Value = state[Value] & {record & [Sprint = CurrentSprint]}
                        ]
                in nextState
        )[Value]
    )
in
    AddedSprint
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!  Thank you very much for such an elaborate answer.  Having working code is very helpful!  In my case, I'm not familiar with M, so this was particularly useful.  I'm currently in the process of adding this to my query.  As part of that process, I'm also reading up on M to get a better understanding of your solution.  Anyway, thanks to your feedback, I now have another learning opportunity.  Kosuke, thanks again for providing me with a solution!

Comment: Thank you for comment @psmurf. M is a powerful, but very easy language to learn. Having a little sense of functional programming (such as Lisp, ML or any) would add it more power. I bet it won't take long time to get familiar with it, and it will be a great addition in your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited number of sprints for your forecast, you could go with the following solution:

**(My table is called: Plan)**

1. Create a column with the following DAX syntax:

`S1 = IF(SUMX(FILTER(Plan, Plan[Priority] <= EARLIER(Plan[Priority])), Plan[Story Points]) > 10, 0, SUMX(FILTER(Plan, Plan[Priority] <= EARLIER(Plan[Priority])), Plan[Story Points]))`

S1 will return the cumulated value for every entry that is in Sprint 1.

2. Create n calculated measures/column depending on the number of sprints you want to forecast. (This is the bad thing about this solution as it does not scale):

`S2 = IF(SUMX(FILTER(Plan, Plan[S1] = 0 && Plan[Priority] <= EARLIER(Plan[Priority])), Plan[Story Points]) > 10, 0, SUMX(FILTER(Plan, Plan[S1] = 0 && Plan[Priority] <= EARLIER(Plan[Priority])), Plan[Story Points]))`

`S3 = IF(SUMX(FILTER(Plan, Plan[S2] = 0 && Plan[S1] = 0 && Plan[Priority] <= EARLIER(Plan[Priority])), Plan[Story Points]) > 10, 0, SUMX(FILTER(Plan, Plan[S1] = 0 && Plan[S2] = 0 && Plan[Priority] <= EARLIER(Plan[Priority])), Plan[Story Points]))`

`S4 = IF(SUMX(FILTER(Plan, Plan[S2] = 0 && Plan[S3] = 0 && Plan[S1] = 0 && Plan[Priority] <= EARLIER(Plan[Priority])), Plan[Story Points]) > 10, 0, SUMX(FILTER(Plan, Plan[S1] = 0 && Plan[S2] = 0 && Plan[S3] = 0 && Plan[Priority] <= EARLIER(Plan[Priority])), Plan[Story Points]))`

3. Create a new measure that returns the string related to the S1-S4 calculated measures:

`Sprint = IF(Plan[S1] > 0, 1, IF(Plan[S2] > 0, 2, IF(Plan[S3] > 0, 3, IF(Plan[S4] > 0, 4))))`

4. Go ahead and hide the S1-S4 columns...

If you have a limited number of sprints to forecast, this might be the way to go...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Fabian,  Thank your very much for your reply.  I have an unknown number of sprints to forecast.  It will depend upon the number of tasks in the backlog.  However, looking at your solution is giving me additional ideas.  Thanks again.

Comment: @psmurf I see two different approaches that could work: If you are loading it through SQL, this is easy enough. If not, in Power Query Editor, you are able to use Python or R scripts. This could help as well, but I am no expert with those.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a REST call and I can't control the returned results.  However, I like your idea about using R or Python.  I'm not familiar with either, but if I don't get a DAX solution, it's a great opportunity to learn something new.  If I do go this route, I'll include it in the answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using the Floor Function.

In Dax, I created a calculated column as such:

`Sprint.Forecast = FLOOR(SheetName[cumulative.points],10)/10+1`

It can also be done in excel using the floor function. Assuming the Cumulative Points column is in C you could get your forecast column by takeing
`=FLOOR(C2,10)/10+1`

Comment: Thanks for looking at this for me.  Unfortunately, similar to my original attempt, it isn't quite right.  In this case, I believe that the 11th item will included in sprint 3 for a total of 11 Story Points which exceeds the Velocity.  On the plus side, I am now familiar with the FLOOR function.  Thanks Zach.